# Replace checkbox with a star image to emphasise it in Android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a list view page in my Android application where each row contains/displays text, date and checkbox.

If the **checkbox** is selected, it means that the particular row in the list is important.
Now I want to replace the **checkbox** with the star image to indicate the row is important. The list page code follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/background_activated">

  <CheckBox android:id="@+id/note_list_item_solvedCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:padding="4dp" />

  <TextView android:id="@+id/note_list_item_titleTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/note_list_item_solvedCheckBox"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:text="Note title" />

  <TextView android:id="@+id/note_list_item_dateTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/note_list_item_titleTextView"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/note_list_item_solvedCheckBox"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anybody give me the code to replace the checkbox with my star image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucky for you I just made this, create a selector in drawable as such:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/star_checked" />
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/star_checked" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/star_unchecked" />
</selector>
```

and then your `CheckBox`:

```
<CheckBox
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/checkBoxFavourite"
   android:button="@drawable/selector_checkbox" <!-- this is the important line -->
   android:gravity="center"
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
   android:focusable="false"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write your own custom control class for this and use the same in your layout file to replace the CheckBox.

Or else, simply have two images star_unactive & star_active in your drawable folders and associate these with a image view. You will have to implement the toggle logic in your adapter class.

Replace the "checkBox" in your listView's row layout file with a "ImageView". Set listeners to this ImageView. Implement the toggle on-off logic to it. When toggled on set star_active image or else set star_unactive image.